# Conditional moments of bivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, bivariate, truncation

Suppose that (X,Y) are bivariate normal with non-zero means and correlation. Is there any neat expression for $\mathbb{E}(X|Y>0)$?

Comment: Since $\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]=\rho y$, what about integrating $\rho y$ over the positive half-line?

Comment: @Xi'an I think the nonzero means need to be taken into account too.

Comment: @Xi'an So, you mean to use $\mathbb{E}[X|Y>0] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X|Y)|Y>0]$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/385423/multivariate-normal-expectation-of-x-given-y-is-doubly-truncated?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal/