# What is E[X|Y>c] where Y=X+Z, and X, Z are normally distributed rvs?

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditioning

Suppose X, Z are normally distributed random variables and independent ($X$ follows $N(\mu,\sigma^{2})$ and $Z$ follows $N(0,\sigma_{z}^{2})$), and that Y=X+Z.

What is E[X|Y>c], where c is just a constant - how do you derive this?

Comment: Are X and Z independent? If not are they bivariate normal and if so what is the correlation between them?

Comment: yes X Z are independent

Comment: Are they standard normal? If not, what are the means and variances of X and Z?

Comment: ideally as generic as possible. let's say $X$ follows $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Z$  follows $N(0,\sigma_{z}^2)$

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal/357176#357176

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read the associated [wiki page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for advices on how to ask a `self-study` question on this forum.