# Condition Random Variable on Range of Another Random Variable

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, joint-distribution, conditional-expectation, multivariate-distribution

Assume that $v_s \sim N(\mu_s,\sigma_s^2)$ and $v_b \sim N(\mu_b,\sigma_b^2)$, denote their correlation by $\rho$, and assume they are jointly normally distributed. How would I assess $E[v_b|v_s\leq c]$ where $c$ is some constant?

I figured it would be of the form $$E[v_b|v_s\leq c]=\frac{1}{P(v_s\leq c)}\int_{-\infty}^cE[v_b|v_s]f_{v_s}dv_s$$ however I'm not sure this is right. Not sure how to conceptualize the approach here. Thanks!

Comment: You can't evaluate this expectation unless you [make a more specific assumption about the joint distribution:](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159) most likely you intend for it to be Binormal.  In that case your question is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023 (because having nonzero means is a trivial complication).  Otherwise, what do you want to assume about the joint distribution?

Comment: A possible approximate solution via a numerical method? Start with the associated conditional Normal given a point in the interval, which is well known (a source of the Expected value and height of the PDF at that point). Average the Probability X  Expected values over a grid of points in the interval of interest. Apply a probability normalization factor, given that the value is in the cited interval.