# Distribution of X given Y>0 with X and Y jointly normal

Tags: conditional-expectation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal with mean $(\mu_X,\mu_Y)^T$ and covariance matrix $\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_x^2 & \rho \\ \rho & \sigma_Y^2\end{pmatrix}$. How can I compute the expectation and variance of $X|Y>0$?

Is it valid to write $\mathbb{E}(X|Y>0) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)f_Y(y) dy$, where $f_Y$ is the marginal density of $Y$?

Comment: Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/356023/119261 and its linked posts.

Comment: Oh amazing, thanks so much!