# Mean of a truncated normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, truncated-normal-distribution

Start with a normal distribution with mean M and standard deviation S. Now exclude all values below the Kth percentile. What is the mean of the remaining 100%-K% of the values as a function of M and S?

I'd just like a simple answer and don't need a proof or generalization which are provided in lengthy answers to related questions which don't actually provide a simple equation from which to compute the answer, and assume the reader knows the difference between the functions  and Φ (I don't):

[Expected value of x in a normal distribution, GIVEN that it is below a certain value (2 answers)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/expected-value-of-x-in-a-normal-distribution-given-that-it-is-below-a-certain-v)
[Expectation of truncated normal (3 answers)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/356023/expectation-of-truncated-normal)

Comment: It's just the expected value for truncated normal, you are looking for how it was derived?

Answer (score 2):

This is the [one-sided truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) with mean and variance given by:

- $\mathbb{E}(X | X>a) = \mu + \sigma \phi(\alpha)/Z$
- $Var( X|X>a) = \sigma^2[1+\alpha\phi(\alpha)/Z - (\phi (\alpha)/Z)^2 ]$

where $\alpha=(a-\mu)/\sigma$  and  $Z = 1-\Phi(\alpha)$.

In your case, you'd plug in $a = 0.98$.